# jQuery Local Storage ( Switch Mode Color Web site )

Tags: jquery, local-storage

**jQuery Local Storage ( Switch Mode Color Web site )**

When attempting to use local storage on this code, not working

 how to use local storage in this code

```
<link id="color1" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/color1.css" />
```

```
<div class="switch_mode hide-el text-center">
    <div class="mode_colors">
        <h4>Choose Your Color</h4>
        <ul>
            <li class="color1" data-theme="assets/css/colors/color1.css"></li>
            <li class="color2" data-theme="assets/css/colors/color2.css"></li>
            <li class="color3" data-theme="assets/css/colors/color3.css"></li>
            <li class="color4" data-theme="assets/css/colors/color4.css"></li>
            <li class="color5" data-theme="assets/css/colors/color5.css"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show_mode"><i class="fa fa-cog" title="Switch Mode"></i></a>
</div>
```

```
$(".switch_mode ul li.color1").click(function() {
    $("head link#color1").attr("href", $(this).data("theme"));
});
$(".switch_mode ul li.color2").click(function() {
    $("head link#color1").attr("href", $(this).data("theme"));
});
$(".switch_mode ul li.color3").click(function() {
    $("head link#color1").attr("href", $(this).data("theme"));
});
$(".switch_mode ul li.color4").click(function() {
    $("head link#color1").attr("href", $(this).data("theme"));
});
$(".switch_mode ul li.color5").click(function() {
    $("head link#color1").attr("href", $(this).data("theme"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved your problem by using localStorage.setItem and $(this).attr("data-theme").

```
localStorage.setItem('color', colorValue);
localStorage.getItem('color');
$(this).attr("data-theme");
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/xxVgqOR)

Comment: Thank you, this is worked but not worked for me, When choosing a color, do not save in local storage.